# Is it possible to use google analytics to prevent click fraud to accurately increment post view counter?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm looking for a service that will provide me analytics to prevent click fraud for saving views in a view_counter in a post table. So basically like this:

->Someone visits one of my sites posts

->Analytics service sends me a response that tells me if the view is an organic click, or a robotic click fraud scam

->If the click is organic the view_counter column is incremented on the post table in the database.

Note I don't want to manually hook each post to something that will be able to do this. I would like to automate the task. So when the post is made on my site the service is automatically set up to count those views and send me a response, so I can save it in the database.

I'm looking at some of the [I'm looking at some of the reporting APIs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/?csw=1), but am unsure what one I would attempt to use and how I would implement this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's help but first of all you have to decide what a good session is. For example you can count only sessions with some duration or some user interactions or maybe if user scroll the page. 
And then you can make an advanced segment for these sessions and make custom report for all your articles. 
Or export your data to Google Sheets and create a table with all your pages and "good sessions" for them.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on?hl=en